# Notification only displayed in Emulators (API15)

Tags: java, android, notifications

I am running a service which will check a csv file for entries and display notification accordingly. The code is fine, the app also works on the emulator running the minimum target API (API 15). However in all my phones, running Jellybean and above, there is no notification displayed.

Here is my service code:

```
public class NotificationActivity extends IntentService {

public NotificationActivity() {
    super("NotificationActivity");
}

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 

     try {

         URL csvURL = new URL("http://example.com/example.csv");
         BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(csvURL.openStream()));
         CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(in, ',', '\'', 1);                
         String [] nextLine;
            while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {

           NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
           mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
           mBuilder.setContentTitle("Title");
           mBuilder.setContentText(nextLine[4] + nextLine[13]);
           mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
           NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

           if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
               mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.getNotification());
            } else {
                mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
            }


        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    stopSelf();
}

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // I want to restart this service again in 30 mins
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm.set(
            alarm.RTC_WAKEUP,
            System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000 * 60 * 30),
            PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, new Intent(this, NotificationActivity.class), 0)
        );
    }
}
```

I realise i shouldn't be using StrictMode.setThreadPolicy, but its a periodic event so i feel it wont cause much trouble to the app.

Why is it not displaying notifications on API16 and above?

Comment: Does it work on an emulator running API 16 or above, or is it only working for API 15 on both the emulator and devices.

Comment: Did you check `logcat`?

Comment: @zgc7009 I don't have an ICS device, but none of my devices show the notification. The notifications are displayed fine on API15 emulator, but are not displayed on API21 emulators also. Maybe an API bug, but i'm not able to rectify.

Comment: `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
               mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.getNotification());
            } else {
                mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
            }` 

is likely the cause of your problem, seeing as that is API dependent.

Comment: @zgc7009 i added that hoping it will fix the issue, a stackoverflow question had this answer. The issue was present before i added the condition too.

Comment: Is it getting an error or is it just not showing up? Seems weird.

Comment: @zgc7009 No errors. Just doesn't show up, rest of the app works fine. There's nothing fishy with the logcat too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. There is no problem in the source, but the CSVReader i use (opencsv) probably does not support newer APIs. Since it did not support, it never executed the CSV Reader. I switched to Apache Commons CSV and it works fine.